# Facebook Messenger Send returns "No matching user found"

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to send a message to a user from my server once they've finished successfully updating their payment details in a Facebook Messenger Webview, just before I close the webview window and return to the chat.

I'm sending a POST message, as defined, to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=*ABC* In the format of:

```
{
  "recipient": {
    "id": 123456789
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "hello, world!"
  }
}
```

...where *123456789* is the valid Page Scoped User Id of the person I'm messaging (currently, that person is an admin of the app while we're in development).

The response I get is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) No matching user found",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 2018001,
        "fbtrace_id": "CTdzskm/2rM"
    }
}
```

Nothing I do seems to change this. I simply cannot get my application to send a message to the Facebook Messenger chat via cURL.

Comment: Are you only unable to send a message after the webview, or is it that you can never send a message?

Comment: @amuramoto - I can never send one.

Comment: Have you run your token through the FB token debugger to see if it has the pages_messaging permission?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

Comment: @amuramoto - Yeah, it seems fine.
https://imgur.com/a/c3HZx

Comment: If you can't send the person a message, how are they opening the webview in Messenger?

Comment: I can send messages via webhooks in API.AI to open a webview.
When I try to get my server to directly send a message to the same conversation, it doesn't work. It says "No matching user found".

Comment: Two questions:

1. Can you post the body of the request being sent by API.ai?
2. Is API.ai using the same page-scoped access token as your app that's trying to send the follow up message?

Comment: No, API.AI was using a different access token! 
When I used API.AI's token, the message worked. Let's be super clear here, I was getting my Access Token from Dashboard > Messenger > Settings > Token Generation (Select page -> Generate).
The token that actually works comes from:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={ID}&client_secret={SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials

@amuramoto - Thank you!

Comment: Great! I've added an answer in case anyone encounters this issue in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the same page-scoped access token to send the new message that was used when you received the person's PSID.